# Shift DataFrame Columns Up Based on Threshold Value found in Columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following df:

```
                           testcol_45    testcol_76    testcol_99
dates                                                   
2020021918                 -1.33           -1.29           -1.38   
2020022000                 -1.24           -1.33           -1.29   
2020022006               -999.00           -1.23           -1.33   
2020022012                 -0.88         -999.00           -1.21   
2020022018                 -0.70           -0.88         -999.00   
2020022100                 -0.46           -0.70           -0.89   
2020022106                 -0.37           -0.45           -0.70
```

I would like to shift the columns up, and not include the cells containing the -999 values once a -999 is reached for every column.

My desired result would look like the following:

```
                           testcol_45    testcol_76    testcol_99
dates                                                   
2020021918                 -0.88           -0.88           -0.89   
2020022000                 -0.70           -1.70           -0.70   
2020022006                 -0.46           -0.45              
2020022012                 -0.37                           
2020022018                                                    
2020022100                                                    
2020022106
```

(The length of column once this operation is achieved does not matter in this case; additionally the column names can be named anything so I cannot reference them by name).

I have tried various iterations of `df.ffill` and `df.bfill`, however to no avail.

Thank you for your time in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can mask the top with `nan` and use the ideas in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33676133/shifting-values-to-the-top-in-a-python-dataframe-if-nan-values-are-encountered) to shift the data. For example, you can mask with:

```
df.where(df.eq(-999)[::-1].cumsum().eq(0))
```

Output:

```
            testcol_45  testcol_76  testcol_99
dates                                         
2020021918         NaN         NaN         NaN
2020022000         NaN         NaN         NaN
2020022006         NaN         NaN         NaN
2020022012       -0.88         NaN         NaN
2020022018       -0.70       -0.88         NaN
2020022100       -0.46       -0.70       -0.89
2020022106       -0.37       -0.45       -0.70
```

Comment: The output is different from the expected output (nans should be at the bottom)

Comment: That’s not the output. That just the mask then you can use the shift methods given in the linked question.

Comment: The shifting is reversed here!

Comment: @RedowanDelowar again, that’s only the masking. Shift methods are **linked**.

Comment: Fancy solution - to get the NaNs on top via the link in the answer: ```df = df.apply(lambda x: x.shift(-x.index.get_loc(x.first_valid_index())))```- do you mind explaining exactly how your solution works?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the index of the row with -999 and shift the column values.

```
(
    df.reset_index()
    .apply(lambda x: x.shift(-x.eq(-999).idxmax()-1) if x.eq(-999).any() else x)
    .set_index('dates')
)


            testcol_45  testcol_76  testcol_99
dates           
2020021918  -0.88       -0.88       -0.89
2020022000  -0.70       -0.70       -0.70
2020022006  -0.46       -0.45       NaN
2020022012  -0.37       NaN         NaN
2020022018  NaN         NaN         NaN
2020022100  NaN         NaN         NaN
2020022106  NaN         NaN         NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's find out the indices where `-999.0` occurs, then iterate through the columns and shift each of them from the bottom.

```py
# resetting the index for flattening the dataframe
df.reset_index(inplace=True)

for col in df.columns:
    try:
        # finding the index where -990 occurs
        n_shift = df.index[df[col] == -999.0].tolist()[0] + 1

        # shifting the column from bottom
        df[col] = df[col].shift(-n_shift)

        print(f"Shifted : {col}")
    except IndexError:
        print(f"Not shifted : {col}")

# setting the index back to original
df.set_index(["dates"], inplace=True)
```

This prints out:

```py
Not shifted : dates
Not shifted : testcol_45
Not shifted : testcol_76
Not shifted : testcol_99
```

The dataframe looks like this:

```py
            testcol_45  testcol_76  testcol_99
dates                                         
2020021918       -0.88       -0.88       -0.89
2020022000       -0.70       -0.70       -0.70
2020022006       -0.46       -0.45         NaN
2020022012       -0.37         NaN         NaN
2020022018         NaN         NaN         NaN
2020022100         NaN         NaN         NaN
2020022106         NaN         NaN         NaN
```